# Disadvantage of Visual Studio Ultimate trial version

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Are there any disadvantage when creating a commercial software in a Visual Studio Ultimate trial version? Can you please point out some effects of a trial version in case I create a simple software from it. Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the licensing terms already? Have you tried anything already?

Comment: Why haven't you at least _tried_ to read the license that ships with your copy of MSVC? Why do you give orthogonal comments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well the biggest disadvantage is that if you want to actually distribute the software you have created using the trial version then you are breaking the EULA.  Other than that, no, it has the same capabilities as the full version of VS Ultimate.

If you are looking to purchase a version of Visual Studio, you might want to look into getting a cheaper version like VS Professional (US$800 vs US$3800!).

Or if you are just having a play around, why not try one of the Express versions: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express.

Comment: what must be added is that the capabilities may be the same, but they are in some cases limited.

Answer (score 3):

From [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/try) site:

"Customers can evaluate Visual Studio 2010 editions free for 90 days. After 30 days, customers must register trials of Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, Premium, and Professional to obtain a free key which extends the trial an additional 60 days."

So there is no drawback other than you can't support anything you created with a nonfunctional software after 90 days (and breaking the license as link664 pointed out). If you're doing commercially software you should consider buying a license. For start ups there are programs like BizSpark which make the investments lower. If you do not want to pay anything look for an alternative. There is SharpDevelop out there.